# Vector of doubles/ints template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I have a function that I'd like to generalize. Simply put, I have a `std::string s` that I process with a parser generating a `std::vector<std::string>` (it's a list as in `"1, 2, 3"`), and the function should return a `std::vector<T>`, with `T` restricted to `double` or `int`.

The vector should contain the transformed values.

I am stuck with the last parameter of `std::transform`, as it should switch between `std::stod` and `std::stoi`. The solution I am looking for is with *template metaprogramming* magic, not with `if (std::is_same<T,int>::value)`.

Any hints?

```
template <class T>
auto get_vector(std::string s) -> std::vector<T>
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    auto tmp = split(s);

    std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::back_inserter(v), ??);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: add a specialization for `double`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is utilize a [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and have the `stringstream` do the conversion for you.  Something like

```
std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::back_inserter(v),
    [](const std::string& elem) -> T
    {
        std::stringstream ss(elem);
        T value;
        ss >> value;
        return value;
    });
```

Comment: Only do this if the amount of data is very small so you don't care if it is ridiculously slow.

Answer (score 7):

Dispatching to `std::stoi` and `std::stod` via function template specialization:

```
template <typename T>
auto parse_number(std::string const& s) -> T;

template <>
auto parse_number<int>(std::string const& s) -> int
{
    return std::stoi(s);
}

template <>
auto parse_number<double>(std::string const& s) -> double
{ 
    return std::stod(s);
}

template <class T>
auto get_vector(std::string const& s) -> std::vector<T>
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    auto tmp = split(s);
    std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::back_inserter(v), &parse_number<T>);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. In short, OP needs to call `some_lexical_caster<T>(const std::string&)`. Actually you might as well use Boost's if this ever needs a more general solution. But, for our purposes here, this `parse_number` is just fine.

Comment: The A.S.H.'s answer is intriguing, and it allows me to avoid specializations. Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: @senseiwa yes, `std::stringstream` may be much slower. It really depends on efficiency of your `split`.

Comment: @senseiwa, also I am not sure what is stringstream going to do with commas in your string. Pretty sure it does not work.

Comment: @senseiwa there is no issue whatsowever about speed, it only depends if you prefer simple an direct solutions or ones that create 3 template declarations to dispatch two single line functions.

Answer (score 3):

Using `istream_iterator`:

```
template <class T>
auto get_vector(std::string s) -> std::vector<T> {
    std::vector<T> v;
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<T>(iss), std::istream_iterator<T>(), std::back_inserter(v));
    return v;
}
```