# Pairs and stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stringstream, std-pair

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028896/vector-of-doubles-ints-template-function) I have asked how I could read and comfortably transform a vector of strings into a vector of integers or doubles.

Now I am expanding that vector of simple types to vector of **pairs** of types (consider `int`, `double`, or even `std::string`, all stream-enabled types) separated by colons.

Example:

```
time:5, length:10
```

Should be read as a `std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>`, with something like this:

```
// Here declare what to parse: a string and an uint, separated by a colon
get_vector<std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>>(s);
```

How can I write a `std::stringstream` operator that does the trick?

I cannot figure how (or even if) I could play with `getline` (my code follows). I'd really like to leave the `get_vector` function **as it is**, if possible.

Thanks!

```
template <class F, class S>
std::stringstream& operator >> (std::stringstream& in, std::pair<F, S> &out)
{
    in >> out.first >> out.second;
    return in;
}

template <class T>
auto get_vector(std::string s) -> std::vector<T>
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    // Vector of strings
    auto tmp = split(s);

    // Magic
    std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::back_inserter(v),
                   [](const std::string& elem) -> T
                   {
                       std::stringstream ss(elem);
                       T value;
                       ss >> value;
                       return value;
                   });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: So in your code `elem` would be the string `"time:5, length:10"`?

Comment: When you say you want to leave the get_vector function as it is, you mean the declaration and not the definition, or do you?

Comment: @NathanOliver elem would be "time:5", since the original string has been split into its comma separated components.

Comment: @ChristianHackl if possible I'd like it to be exactly as it is, that's why I think an operator is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator>>` receives a `std::stringstream` which in that moment contains a string like `"time:5"`. The operator needs to parse that string by splitting it up into two tokens, then convert the first token to an `F` and the second to an `S`.

One way to do this is to use `std::getline` with a custom delimiter. You will end up with two `std::string` tokens. These can be converted, for example, with two internal `std::istringstream`s.

Here is some code you can try:

```
template <class F, class S>
std::stringstream& operator >> (std::stringstream& in, std::pair<F, S> &out)
{
    std::string first_token;
    std::string second_token;
    std::getline(in, first_token, ':');
    std::getline(in, second_token);

    std::istringstream first_converter(first_token);
    std::istringstream second_converter(second_token);

    first_converter >> out.first;
    second_converter >> out.second;

    return in;
}
```

You may want to add some error handling for the case when there is no `':'` in the string.

---

Note that you should not use `std::stringstream` if you do not want to combine input and output. Most of the times, you will want either `std::istringstream` or `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

> Because I am new in English I am not sure to **understand** what you want.
>   I jest seeing that @Christian Hackl do what. So if this answer does not
>   relate to what you want please tell me and I will **delete** it.

I assume you need to extract a **string** from *string* or *stream* and then put them into a `vector` that contains a `std::pair< std::string, std::size_t >`

Say you have this string that can be an input-stream, too:
`std::string string( "one:1, two:20, three:300, four:40000, five:500000" );`

There is more than one way to do it, but I say it in this way!
So first you need to **split** this string and then put what has split, in to **vector of pair**.

```
std::string string( "one:1, two:20, three:300, four:40000, five:500000" );

std::stringstream io_stream;

std::basic_regex< char > regex( ", " );
std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::const_iterator > last;
std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::const_iterator > first( string.begin(), string.end(), regex, -1 );

std::vector< std::pair< std::string, std::size_t > > vector_of_pair;
std::string str_pair( "" );
std::size_t ui_pair( 0 );

while( first != last ){
    io_stream.clear();
    io_stream.seekg( 0 );
    io_stream.seekp( 0 );

    io_stream << *first << '\n';
    std::getline( io_stream, str_pair, ':' );
    // error:
    // no match function to call: stream and int
    // std::getline( io_stream, ui_pair);
    io_stream >> ui_pair;

    vector_of_pair.emplace_back( str_pair, ui_pair );

    ++first;
}
```

**test**

```
for( std::size_t index = 0; index < vector_of_pair.size(); ++index ){
    std::cout << vector_of_pair[ index ].first << " and " << vector_of_pair[ index ].second << '\n';
}
```

**output**

```
one and 1
two and 20
three and 300
four and 40000
five and 500000
```

**how it work**
There is no difficult code to understand. It just by `std::regex_token_iterator` splits the string, then in a **while** loop send the value of it to `is_stream`, then **read the line** and send it to `str_pair`, but here because `std::getline` has not function to extracts `int` type, I used `>>` of `stringstream` itself, then `emplace_back` to vector and that's it.

**NOTE**
For:
How can I write a std::stringstream operator that does the trick?
I think now you can do it by yourself. Since I was not sure, I have not written the code with `operator>>`.